# Retrieval of data from a table when you have details of a particular column

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I have a table which contains details of customers and all i have is the customer number
and i need to retrieve , the firstname , accountnumber from the database

eg: select firstname,accountnumber from customer_account where customer_number in (
'09000',
'00011'
)

i need to create an app in oracle apex that will allow prompt the user to input the customer number inorder to obtain
the firstname and account number

Comment: What is your question? Your example query looks correct for your needs.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way - from my point of view - is to create an **interactive report** (IR) based on `customer_account` table. As its name suggests, it is *interactive* and lets user do various things with data.

Really simple filtering is done via IR's "Search" field - just type something, and Apex will search all rows for that string. There's also more advanced filtering available via IR's **Action** button (menu).

If you want to do it manually, sure you can: create additional text item, submit when ENTER is pressed (or create a button which will submit) and modify report's query so that it searches for values user enters. For example:

```
select ca.firstname, ca.accountnumber
from customer_account ca join
  (select trim(regexp_substr(:P1_SEARCH_ITEM, '[^,]+', 1, level)) value
   from dual
   connect by level <= regexp_count(:P1_SEARCH_ITEM, ',') + 1
  ) b on instr(ca.customer_number, b.value) > 0;
```

You'd enter e.g. `09000, 00111` into that item (without any quotes).